# Полноэкранный режим. Мерцания.

Tags: delphi, opengl

Доброго вечера! Разрабатываю 2д игру на Delphi + OpenGl. Имеется карта размером, например, 40х40, а на мониторе выводится некоторая часть карты 20х20. Вывод карты делаю двумерным массивом, что собственно должно наоборот повысить фпс игры. Все отлично работает, но когда перехожу в полноэкранный режим при движении, на карте появляются некие "мерцания", как будто вывод у меня не успевает за движением. Но это лишь кажется на первый взгляд.

Если поставить размер формы не в полноэкранный режим, а например так:

```
Frmgl.Height:=Screen.Height;
Frmgl.Width:=Screen.Width-1;
```

то все работает безупречно! Вся проблема заключается в том, что я перевожу приложением в полноэкранный режим. Михаил Фленов писал на счет этого бага и выход из него он нашел, просто в создании формы пишем:

```
WindowState := wsMaximized;
```

Скидывал игру одному человеку и у него, как он мне говорил, ничего не мерцало, а у другого есть... Хотя сам тестировал на 3-х компьютерах с разной конфигурацией и ничего не изменилось, мерцания остаются, из-за чего - уже второй день понять не могу.

Дабы вы поняли в чем дело я залил ссылку:
http://narod.ru/disk/38902687001/0.0.1BA.zip.html

P.S в файле Options в первой строке пишем:
*BorderStyle=BsSingle*, если хотим не полноэкранный режим, а если же наоборот то *BorderStyle=BsNone*

Comment: Программа должна определять в каком разрешении она запущена (или сама устанавливать это разрешение). В зависимости от этого уже отсчитываются координаты координаты элементов интерфейса и прочего. Худший вариант - можно сделать чтобы игра поддерживала единственное разрешение, например 1024x768.

Comment: Старую проблему решил и теперь появилась новая.

Comment: Неужели никто не знает, как решить данную проблему? Ни за что не поверю. Ответьте, пожалуйста, люди.

Comment: У меня ничего не мерцает. А какая новая проблема-то?

Comment: Да собственно мерцание - есть моя проблема. Ну никак понять не могу почему у меня мерцает, а других все ок?

Comment: Не мерцает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся проблема заключалась в неправильной двойной буферизации. Вроде все верно, но не работало... И работало без мерцания у людей с включенной двойной буферизацией в настройках видеокарты. Быть может кому-то в будущем поможет)